# How can I handle this cell-lock in excel? (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

So with a macro I can create new sheets, in which some cells will be locked. I use this method in the macro:

`ActiveSheet.Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=False` (for the whole new sheet)
Then in this macro for some cells: `locked = False`

Then with the locked property, other macros switch particular cells's locking using True or False. For example a table in this sheet is locked, but a button's macro recount and rewrite the values of the table, and to do this, at the beginning of the macro the `table.Locked = False`, and at the end of the macro `Locked = True` again.

But when I save the excel, close and open it again, I push the button, but I get `"unable to set the Locked property"`

How should I do this?

update:

```
Sub userinterface()

ActiveSheet.Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True

End Sub


Sub locking()

Range("A1").Locked = False
Range("A1") = 5
Range("A1").Locked = True

End Sub
```

So I have a new sheet, and I run the userinterface macro. It locks the whole sheet. Then I run the locking macro, that writes 5 in the given cell and locks the cell again. After it I save the excel, close and open it, and I just want to run the locking macro. At this point I get the error.

Comment: Máté, what we need is a minimal, complete, and verifiable example to reproduce the problem as outlined here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Without that I have a difficult time understand the problem you seem to experience and cannot reproduce it (in order to solve it). So, please add the complete code you are currently using to lock your file (all relevant macros and where they are placed: for example as worksheet events or executed as an event when the file is closed, etc.). Maybe then we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Of course, it will be short.

Comment: Is this all your code? There is nothing to indicate this should not be working just fine? You say `table.locked = False` in your questions but the code says otherwise?

Comment: The code is much longer, but just using this the problem is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the `UserInterfaceOnly` option is not stored with the file and after reopening, the sheet is fully protected and you can't unlock cells on a protected sheet.

You can reset the `UserInterfaceOnly` option without unprotecting so in your example it would be

```
Sub locking()

    ActiveSheet.Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True
    Range("A1").Locked = False
    Range("A1") = 5
    Range("A1").Locked = True

End Sub
```

Of course in this example unlocking the cell is not necessary because you have set the option to true but I assume that it's relevant in your full macro.

Comment: Thanks, it would be good. I thought that the userinterfaceonly protection will lock the unlocked cells, but as I see it doesn't. So I just have to write that at the beginning of the macros.